# How to manage the sections of a website with Django?

Tags: django

am a newbie in Django, and am developing my first website with this framework. Is it correct to make one app for each section (home, about, contact), or I have to make one app that contains ALL the website?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd make one app that contains the whole website. You can use different templates for different sections.

Comment: apps are called to be the logical web applications so one app for one web applications as simple as potato

Comment: Thanks Jared and Arpit for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of an art to determine how to split up a Django project, and you likely won't get it right the first time. Without knowing more about the actual functionality of your site it's a bit hard to tell.

If each one of these sections has its own custom functionality, I'd put them in separate applications. As the functionality of each section grows (e.g. you may end up with a few views for your contact section, which'd warrant its own app), you won't end up with unwieldy `views` or `models` modules, which is what happens when you try to put everything in the one app.

If one of these sections is just a standard content page, consider using the [flatpages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/flatpages/) app as it may save you a lot of time.

As I said, this is something that'll just get easier with time. You will get a feel for how much code is required for certain pieces of functionality, and get a feel for what is a manageable / unmanageable amount of code, and 'naturally' split your projects up accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kye! :D